# Migrating to log4j2 with referenced libraries using log4j

Tags: java, logging, openshift, apache-axis, log4j2

We have a web services application running on Jboss Openshift using Apache Axis2. We are migrating to log4j2. However apart from our application logs some logs of the reference libraries such as axis2 logs, hazelcast logs are getting logged using log4j. We came to this conclusion as they are still using the old log4.properties file instead of the log4j2.xml file. Our application is using the log4j2.xml file. Hence 2 log files are getting created, one for log4j and one for log4j2. We tried adding the adapter jars provided in the migration guide and also removed all references to log4j jars but to no avail. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the logs are still being logged using the log4j.properties then there is still a copy of log4j on the classpath. If you remove log4j.properties you should see log4j emit a warning about not being configured.  So long as that appears log4j is still present.

Comment: However on removing the log4j.properties file, I dont see any warning by log4j...Is there any way I can turn on logging for log4j?

Comment: Hey I can see the following line in maven build on jenkins...It seems to be downloading to the log4j.pom but I am not able to find out what is causing it...Please help  
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.pom
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.pom (145 B at 14.2 KB/sec)

Comment: run mvn dependency:tree in the project. That will tell you what is including the dependency up to the point of the dependency in your project. You then need to exclude the log4j dependency in that dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I tried that but nowhere am I able to see the log4j dependency..I even tried with creating the analyze-reports goal but to no avail.